# Training a feedforward net in MATLAB with large amount of data

Tags: matlab, neural-network, large-data

I am a bit new to neural nets. I want to train a neural net with a large data set of two inputs and one output. Here is my code:

```
Qnet1=feedforwardnet(20);
s=[0:10:1600];
a=[1:1:9];
data=[];
for i=1:size(s,2)
    for j=1:size(a,2)
        data=[data,[s(i);a(j)]];
    end
end
Qnet1=configure(Qnet1,data,output);
Qnet1=train(Qnet1,data,output);
```

where "output" is the output vector. However, MATLAB can not train the network.  I don't get any error but the training tool appears not to do anything. No iteration happens and the performance value remains very high (which I guess is not good). But with lower amount of data there is no problem.

Comment: What does "can not train the network" mean? Do you get an error? Does the `train` function never return? Do the weights not converge? Does the network fail to fetch your slippers?

Comment: No I don't get any error but the training tool appears not to do anything. No iteration happens and the performance value remains very high (which I guess is not good). But with lower amount of data there is no problem.

Comment: You wrote that there is no problem with less data. Is it the same code? How do you get from the little data to the big data or vice versa?

Comment: @Framester It wasn't the same code. I just did it manually but now I realized that if my output elements are all the same then the `train`  doesn't work. Is there any way to train my network with an all equal output? Example: `input=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7;7,6,5,4,3,2,1]; output=[5,5,5,5,5,5,5];`

Comment: @Perissiane, no, because this way the network does not know how a negative example would look. Have a look at something like: https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/cancer-detection.html